# Client/Server - Updating an entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, design-patterns

We are using an ORM framework (Hibernate). Our model contains many entities. We use spring framework with angularJS based client. The whole communication is ajax based through REST services. We use mainly DTO Objects between client and server with marshaling of Jackson (json->Pojo). The web application is targeted for mobile as well as for PC (primarily PC).

We are now debating on the flow (client - server) to update an entity. At first glance this looks pretty easy:

1. client sends the update request to the server
2. server executes the update and responds with an acknowledge message.

After discussing the flow in more detail we raised some questions:

1. What exactly should the client send to the server?

   - should it send the whole entity object?
   - should it send a map of (fieldName, NewValue)?
   - if the client does send a map - how does the client knows about the fieldNames? do we need to agree upon pre defined names?
   - if we agree on pre defined names - how the server interprets them? does the server keeps a map of  fieldName - > actual DB fieldName for updates?
2. How does the server executes the update?

   - Should the server execute a different update script for each different field that changed?
   - Should the server execute a single huge update script that is being altered according to the client request?

We have been looking for a day now for articles \ posts about this simple notion and couldn't find any references.

Comment: So, which of these answers was the one you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with this myself and have spent more time than I'd like to admit looking for a clean solution to what appears to be a very simple problem.

On the last project that I worked on, we wrote our own code to handle incoming HTTP PUT requests in a custom format.  The custom format was agnostic to the type of object and worked like a map.  We retrieved instances of our model entities from our service layer, used reflection to apply the changes contained in the patch, and then saved the entities.  It worked, but it was messy.

There is an RFC for a standard [JSON PATCH format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902).  Spring recently came out with something called [Spring Sync](https://spring.io/blog/2014/10/22/introducing-spring-sync) (on [GitHub here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-sync/)) that appears to work with PATCH requests formatted according to the RFC.  I haven't used it, but it looks pretty slick.  If I was starting something new, I'd give it a try.

From what I gather, the usage would look something like this:

```
YourPojo pojo = yourDao.get(...)
Patch patch = JsonPatchMaker.fromJsonNode(yourJacksonJsonNode);
patch.apply(pojo, YourPojo.class);
yourDao.save(pojo);
```

Answer (score 1):

We are following below pattern in our project

What exactly should the client send to the server?

should it send the whole entity object?

=>Depends! How much flexibility you want to give to consumer,We support partial update at our project.

should it send a map of (fieldName, NewValue)?

=>Yes for employee entity if they only wants to update name then below json put to /employee/{id}

```
{
    name:'XYZ'
}
```

if the client does send a map - how does the client knows about the fieldNames? do we need to agree upon pre defined names?

=>It is pre-defiend as by consuming the REST API, Consumer signing a contract so you can enforce this.

if we agree on pre defined names - how the server interprets them? does the server keeps a map of fieldName - > actual DB fieldName for updates?

=?This is standard DTO to Database Entity object conversion and it should be handle by business logic. you can user something like Auto Mapper https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

How does the server executes the update?

=>This is tricky. The way we do, we get the existing entity from database and merge with incoming object and then call update. It get trickier when user intentionally wants to set something NULL. We have solved this problem using special value.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to consider the concurrent access control policy, otherwise you might end-up with [losing updates](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-database-locking-and-the-lost-update-phenomena/).

Since you are dealing with a [multi-request conversation](http://vladmihalcea.com/preventing-lost-updates-in-long-conversations/), the server needs to be stateful to ensure [application-level repeatable reads](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-application-level-repeatable-reads/). [Optimistic locking](http://vladmihalcea.com/an-entity-modelling-strategy-for-scaling-optimistic-locking/) is therefore mandatory for preventing the lost update phenomena.

You shouldn't expose your domain model to the front-end, so it's better to use an intermediate DTO layer instead and a mapping tool like [Dozer](https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer) can ease the pain of populating those DTOs. There are many such [mapper frameworks](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/java-object-to-object-mapper.html) so you can choose the one that best suit your needs.

When the UI wants to render a view, the back-end fetches entities and returns DTOs to front-end. Since a DTO is much slimmer than the original entity, you save bandwidth and it's only the DTOs that need to be serialized as JSON (e.g. which requires @JsonIgnore for cyclic-dependencies).

The DTOs need to be serialized to front-end and so you can use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) for transforming DTOS to JSON objects.

The front-end uses the associated JSON objects, makes changes to these and sends them back for being persisted.

The server-side REST framework unmarshals the JSON objects back to DTOs, and the middle-ware services need to update the conversation-related entities with the current DTO data. So you are actually changing the same objects you loaded for being displayed (in case some other user changed them, you'll get an optimistic locking failure).

Answer (score 1):

**Should it send the whole entity object**
Hibernate will use the identifier of each Entity when persisting them so all that's required is that identifier, but more information is required if you want it to be used. For example, if a user needs edit an Entity, the Entity's identifier and whatever field is changed must be sent in the update request. Unchanged fields do not need to be send, but it's easier to just send them all and let hibernate decide if the value has changed.

**Should it send a Map**
If it makes you happy, yes, you'll just want a solution that allows Jackson to build your DTO on the request receiving end. What I do is send a JSON representation of the DTO, which is pretty mappy so maybe that's what you're meaning.

Say there's a PersonEntity which has fields 'id' and 'name'; the JSON posted when creating one could be  `{ name : 'Bob' }` (and let's say that Person gets id 1), the JSON for editing could be `{ id :1, name : 'Bobby' }`, and the JSON for deleting could be `{ id : 1 }`. In each of these cases, Jackson will map the supplied information to your PersonEntity DTO, setting the 'id' and 'name' fields.

**if the client does send a map - how does the client knows about the fieldNames? do we need to agree upon pre defined names?**
Whichever solution you choose will need to allow Jackson to match the request contents with the fields of your DTO. Having them match makes it easy, but Jackson does allow custom serialization and deserialization implementations so it's possible,

**if we agree on pre defined names - how the server interprets them? does the server keeps a map of fieldName - > actual DB fieldName for updates?**
Let Hibernate handle this. Your configuration or annotations will tell hibernate which Entity fields go to which table columns.

**How does the server executes the update?**
Updates can be executed through the `org.hibernateSession.saveOrUpdate()` method. Hibernate will determine whether the Entity is new or existing based on its persistence state.

**Should the server execute a different update script for each different field that changed?**
One statement execution will be faster. If you turn up Hibernate's logging, I'd wager it's one query for all updates to a row.

**Should the server execute a single huge update script that is being altered according to the client request?**
Hibernate will handle this and it flushes the session (makes the changes happen on the server) when the session is closed, or when flush() is called. The Hibernate documentation on Sessions and on States are quite well written and are found here (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to define these objects both in client and sever. Java has interface for deserialization of json/xml objects to Java defined ones. If some field is different, an error will be raised, so you don't have to worry.
2. It depends on what you want and what your goal is. Pros on update at once (in one transaction): you use one transaction and if something fails everything is rolledback. Cons: if something fails you lose all of the updates.

Answer (score 0):

define simple objects in client, just parameters need to pass.
define DO object in server, which need to save to database.

transform object is json that your choose, that's no problem. [spring rest xml/java JAXB]

develop middle component that change json <==> java object.

Answer (score 0):

This is not truly an answer but an advice. Think whatever the solution you choose about how to detect removed attributes. If you have hierarchicle object structure which contains collections(lists, sets etc.) It will be difficult to detect which elements are modified or deleted. For this reason i have choosen by my project to send and receive the whole object (as json) every time.